# Are these real paths of planets as traced from Earth?

Tags: planet, solar-system, earth, rotation, planetary-transits

Few days a go, I came across these two pictures of paths of planets as observed from Earth. They have a perfect geometric shapes.  Actually, to me they look so beautiful and perfect, that they appear fake or made by a pseudo-scientist or some propaganda society (e.g. flat Earth like community people) who talks about divine geometry etc.

Auxiliary questions: Is this the reason, why Earth was consider to be in the center of the solar system?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: ['Geocentric' view of orbits](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/30176)

Comment: @MikeG sure I'll go through this link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/30184/7982) here are views of the inner and outer planets. I used the python package Skyfield which uses the NASA JPL ephemerides to generate positions of all the planets, then I subtracted the Earth's position to generate the geocentric positions.

I agree with your guess that the first image is too perfect.

The paths will not be closed, because there is not a rational number relationship (e.g. 5:9, 2:3, 1:1) between the periods of the planets.

The ones in the image are *reminiscent of* the [Spirograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirograph) drawings I used to make a very long time ago.

---

> ...plotting using the Python package [Skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/).
>
> The "inner" plotted bodies (from outer to inner) are Mars, (Earth), Moon, Venus, Mercury, The Sun. The data is for **2000 days**.
>
> The "outer" plotted bodies are Uranus, Saturn, Jupiter, Earth, and The Sun. The data is for **2000 months**.
>
> Distances are in AU.
>
> [image: inner and outer planets, heliocentric and geocentric]

Comment: Are those "heliocentric" plots actually heliocentric, or barycentric? Although I do suspect one wouldn't be able to tell the difference at this scale...

Comment: @JohnDvorak yep good point they are barycentric, I'd meant to subtract the Sun's position but it seems I forgot. I think the difference is probably less than 1 pixel, but accuracy is important, so I will regenerate the plots in the morning, and see if the difference is a pixel or not. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnDvorak updated here and [there](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/30184/7982) The difference is roughly 1 vs 150 million km. It looks like more than 1 pixel when I plot them as much larger images and do the RGB subtraction, but then again so do the titles, so I don't think I'll pursue that further. Thanks again! https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcMcp.png